# Analyzing nested for loops

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity

> Analyze the runtime complexity of:
>
> ```
> for(i=1; i <= n; i=i*2)
>   for(j=1; j<= n-i; j++)
>     print j;
> ```

My try:

Writing down the values for `i,j`:

```
i:  1       |   2        |  …|  2^i     |...| 2^log_2(n)=n

j:  1...n-1 |   1...n-2  |   | 1...n-2^i|...| 0
```

So I get the following:

[image]

Is this right? I'm really not sure about the change of variable and the middle sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will look at each part of the loop separately.

The outer loop may be represented as:

```
for(i=1; i <= n; i=i*2)
    f(n, i)
```

Where `f(n,i)` is the inner loop with complexity `O(f)`. This has a complexity of `log(n) * O(f)`.

```
for(j=1; j<= n-i; j++)
    print j;
```

This has a complexity of `n`, since `n` dominates `i`. `i` is a power of two less than `n`, and so their difference is at worst `n - 1`.

Thus the complexity is `log(n) * n` or `nlog(n)`.

Comment: Nice. Is it really ok to split the for loops like that?

Comment: You have to remember the relationship between the loops when you do this.

Comment: By that you mean the `print x`?